# React Native tab view: How to prevent all tabs loading at initial time

Tags: react-native, tabs

I am using this lib `https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-tab-view` for tab view. I have total 4 tabs and each tab's content has API loading. When I open the screen with this tabview. All 4 tabs are loading at the same time. API of each tab is calling parallel. I want first only one tab is initialised then after based on click respective tab is loads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Fixed it by following condition


    renderScene = ({ route }) => {
    if (route.key == 'scene0' && this.state.index == 0) {
      return <Scene0 />;
    }
    if (route.key == 'scene1' && this.state.index == 1) {
      return <Scene1 />;
    }
    if (route.key == 'scene2' && this.state.index == 2) {
      return <Scene2 />;
    }
    if (route.key == 'scene3' && this.state.index == 3) {
          return <Scene3 />;
        }
```

or by adding ***lazy*** flag, we can also acchive the same

```
<TabView
          navigationState={{index, routes}}
          renderScene={renderScene}
          onIndexChange={setIndex}
          initialLayout={{width: wp(100)}}
          renderTabBar={renderTabBar}
          tabBarPosition={'bottom'}
          lazy
        />
```